# How to create a PHP class which only inits once and is used by all users

Tags: php, sockets

I coded one class which deals with socket_create, socket_connect and return the file descriptor of the socket. I want to know how to keep this file descriptor always usable.

After this class is instanced, all sessions use the same instance(file descriptor of the socket) to send and recv data. This socket connection will not be closed automatically.

For example,

```
/*socket_class.php*/
class socket_class {
    private $socket;

    public function getSocket() {
        /*do socket_create and socket_connect*/
        return this->$socket;
    }
}

$socket_instance = new socket_class();

/*socket_user.php*/
require_once("socket_class.php");
$socket_file_descriptor = $socket_instance->getSocket();
/*Send and Recv data*/
```

I just want all the sessions use the same $socket_instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the property static (doesn't need to be instantiated to hold a value).

```
class socket_class {
    private static $socket;

    public function getSocket() {
        /*do socket_create and socket_connect*/
        return self::$socket;
    }
}
```

Note that as per the above code, you do need to use the `self` pseudo-variable; not `$this`.

Comment: I have tried your method before, but it doesn't work. But still thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When web users open php pages on apache, each call starts a separate process independant of the other user. This means that browser based calls will be run separately, each session creating its own class instance.

To bypass this, you need to run a '**daemon**', a php process that keeps running on the server side.

This [link](http://www.funphp.com/?p=33) gives an example procedure to create a socket based daemon. This daemon will run independently of your other code , on a different port on the same server.

From your main website running on apache (port 80), you can call this daemon from javascript, in html etc, at the following url

```
http://yoursite.com:6789/
```

where 6789 is the port you use in the socket server

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
class socket_class {
 private static $socket;
 public function getSocket() {
  return self::$socket;
 }
}
$obj_socket = new socket_class();
$obj_socket->getSocket();
?>
```

in your code public function getSocket() return this->$socket; is replace by return self::$socket; because $socket is a static variable so you can't call it using $this.

Comment: I have tried your method before, but it doesn't work. But still thank you for your help.